# Terraform Cloud - Local file not created in specificed location

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hashicorp, hashicorp-sentinel

### Code

```
resource "local_file" "sample" {
    content = "some text"
    filename = "${path.module}/sample.txt"
 }
```

### File path details

- module

  - local

    - test.tf --- here I pasted the above code
- main.tf
- var.tf

After terraform apply I couldn't see the sample.txt in any of the folder.

Everything looks good. I can see the log as local_file creation but in the specified location new file not created. I'm trying this from windows 10. Also tried from gitlab pipeline cant see the file. Terraform version 14.9 and local provider version is ~2.1.

Please provide a solution for this

Comment: The code is correct and the file should be there. Please make sure your question is fully representative of your use case.

Comment: I just tried your exact setup, and it worked fine. Are you actually using the module in your `main.tf`?

Comment: @lxop can you please share what terraform versions and provider you using. Are you able to see the file created in a specific location.

Comment: TF version v0.14.8, provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local v2.1.0. Yes, the file is created in the local/ directory, beside test.tf.

Comment: Why not use http provider and get content directly?

Comment: @lxop please correct me if I'm wrong. I tried with terraform free verion I can see the file. But its not creating file in terraform enterprise edition.

Comment: Is this remote execution with TF Cloud?

Comment: @MattSchuchard yes.

Comment: The file would then be created in the ephemeral instance spun up by TF Cloud or TFE specifically for the job. You would need to retrieve it somehow during execution. @FranxiHidro comment becomes very relevant in that situation.